# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=DD900 was not working for ddl-auto=update

Tags: spring-boot

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
```

2017-03-24 14:14:17.932 ERROR 8440 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.vezinet.test.Test1Application.main(Test1Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing table metadata
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.locateTableInNamespace(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTable(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTableInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name. 
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:39) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1457) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1462) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setCatalog(SQLServerConnection.java:1767) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.switchCatalogs(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:313) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetFromStoredProc(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:264) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetWithProvidedColumnNames(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:291) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getTables(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:441) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.locateTableInNamespace(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:339) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 31 common frames omitted